# Degree of a field extension for three fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, field-theory

> Given field extension $L/K$ and fields $E_1,E_2$ with $$(1)\ K\subset E_1\subset L,\ [E_1:K]=n_1$$ $$(2)\ K\subset E_2\subset L,\ [E_2:K]=n_2.$$ If $\gcd(n_1,n_2)=1$ then $K=E_1\cap E_2$.

**Proof:** Since $E_1\cap E_2\subset E_1,E_2$ we can write the following:$$(i)\ K\subset E_1\cap E_2\subset E_1,\ n_1=[E_1:K]=[E_1:E_1\cap E_2][E_1\cap E_2:K]$$ $$(ii)\ K\subset E_1\cap E_2\subset E_2,\ n_2=[E_2:K]=[E_2:E_1\cap E_2][E_1\cap E_2:K].$$ Since $\gcd(n_1,n_2)=1$ then $$(a)\ n_1\ |\ [E_1:E_1\cap E_2]$$ $$(b)\ n_2\ |\ [E_2:E_1\cap E_2].$$ Hence $E_1\cap E_2=K$.

Comment: I think you've very close, yet that "hence" may need some further explanation.

Comment: Well I thought, $ deg(E_i:E_1\cap E_2)=r_i<= n_i $ since $n_i|r_i$ then $n_i=r_i\implies K=E_1\cap E_2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost! You have the right idea, but you didn't finish the proof all the way. You have the following:
$$n_1 \mid [E_1 : E_1 \cap E_2] \mid [E_1 : K]=n_1$$
Since $n_1$ is both a divisor and factor of $[E_1 : E_1 \cap E_2]$, we have:
$$[E_1 : E_1 \cap E_2]=n_1 \implies [E_1 : E_2 \cap E_2]=[E_1 : K]$$
Thus, by substitution:
$$[E_1 : K]=[E_1 : E_1 \cap E_2][E_1 \cap E_2 : K] \implies [E_1 : K]=[E_1 : K][E_1 \cap E_2 : K]$$
Now, divide both sides by $[E_1 : K]$:
$$[E_1 \cap E_2 : K]=1 \implies E_1 \cap E_2 = K$$
I'm pretty sure you already knew all of this, but you have to write it all out so that your teacher knows what you are thinking.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Iit was clear but sometimes it is difficult to write it (trivial things )out.